# where is code of search and show entries of datatables in bootstrap theme

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatables, bootstrap-5

I want to change the css property and also need to change the html code for mobile devices of "Show entries" and "Search" of DataTable in bootstrap.

I found this code in the Developer Tools

```
    <div class="dataTables_length" id="tblData_length">
     <label>Show 
     <select name="tblData_length" aria-controls="tblData" class="">
        <option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="200">200</option>
     </select> 
      entries
     </label>
    </div>
Search code is Following:

<div id="tblData_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <label>Search:
        <input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="tblData">
    </label>
</div>
```

Ps. I didn't find the code of "Show entries" and "Search" of DataTable since I am using DataTable using the direct link. So I can't modify the code for search and Show entries either.
How to modify and added my code html code to "Show entries" and "Search"? I don't need to remove it.
Any hint will be appriciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To modify the "Show entries", you have to use the `infoCallback`, e.g.

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "infoCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) {
    return start +" to "+ end;
  }
} );
```

But I'm not sure to understand what you want to do...